# Mule3: RabbitMQ XML schema error?

Tags: rabbitmq, mule

I try to use mule to receieve message from RabbitMQ, and call remote REST service. My configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  version="CE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:amqps="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqps"
  xmlns:amqp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqps http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqps/current/mule-amqps.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/current/mule-amqp.xsd.xsd">

  <amqp:connector name="amqpLocalhostConnector" virtualHost="localhost" username="test" password="abc123"
    activeDeclarationsOnly="true" />

  <flow name="amqpChoiceAckNackService" doc:name="amqpChoiceAckNackService">
    <amqp:inbound-endpoint queueName="my-queue" connector-ref="amqpLocalhostConnector" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081"
      method="POST" path="rmqtest" doc:name="HTTP" />
  </flow>
</mule>
```

And I added the mule-transport-amqp-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar into the classpath, and I checked the schemas, there is definition of connector, but I still got the following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 37; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'amqp:connector'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
  at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
  ... 23 more
```

EDIT:

I use mule studio, check the picture below.

[image: classpath]

Comment: It looks like a problem with your classpath, can you share it with us?

Comment: I use mule studio, see my EDIT, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMQP transport is available as a Studio Plugin through the [MuleStudio Cloud Connectors Update Site](http://repository.mulesoft.org/connectors/releases/2).

By installing it from there you should be able to address the problem. If you need a newer version (i.e. 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT) you can clone the project for its [github location](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-transport-amqp) and package it with maven.

This way you will generate the update site for the transport yourself

Comment: Thanks, I use the new version plugin, It's OK now. But why I add it to classpath, it's not OK?